# Using RxJava for Grouped Moving Average

Tags: java, rx-java2

I can calculate the moving average of a simple integer list easily like:

```
Integer arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};                        
Observable<Integer> oi = Observable.from(arr);                          
oi.buffer(24, 1).subscribe(x -> average(x))
```

Now lets say that I have objects instead of integers like

```
private class Model{
  public String key;
  public Double value;
}
```

where I want to group and calculate the moving average based on `key` in a **non-blocking** fashion (i.e. I am getting a continuous stream from rabbitmq) in way that will emit `{key->average}` values.

I am aware of the `groupBy` operator but things get messy when I use it. What is the best way to do this with `groupBy` ?

Comment: I think you could use groupBy operator for that: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/groupby.html

Comment: @Héctor sorry I wasnt clear. I actually want to know how to do it with the groupBy operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Observable<Model> oi = ...;
oi.groupBy(model -> model.key)
    .flatMapSingle(Observable::toList)
    .subscribe(modelsGrouped -> { // key: modelsGrouped.get(0).key
        double avg = average(modelsGrouped);
        //...
    });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I think `.flatMapSingle(Observable::toList)` is blocking (i.e. waits stream to finish) though since it never reaches the print line. Any other ways to do it?

Comment: I would say that's the way to go. What do you mean with `never reaches the print line`?

Comment: I put a breakpoint there but it never gets there for some reason

Comment: It's working in my machine. Can you show your code? How are you creating the `Observable<Model>`?

Comment: I am using `PublishSubject<Model> s = PublishSubject.create()` and then pushing from values from `rabbitmq` with `onNext`

Comment: It's because you have unfinished source(PublishSubject), call onComplete() on it and it will work. How it is supposed to group elements if its doesn't know when source stops.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of the question is that there is an infinite stream and the goal is to calculate average of a sliding window on the stream. But the question is not clear on details and there are several different ways to interpret it.

```
CASE 1. The sliding window is the most recent 24 items of the stream.
CASE 2. The sliding window is the most recent 24 items per type.
    CASE 2.1 Each emit is the average of the most recent sliding window that has moved.
    CASE 2.2 Each emit should contain averages of all groups.
    CASE 2.3 Or some other forms..
```

It would be helpful if you can give us example inputs and expected outputs.

Following answer is for CASE 2.1:

```
oi.groupBy(model -> model.key) // [1]
        .flatMap(groupedO -> groupedO.buffer(4, 1) // [2]
                .map(list -> {
                    double avg = list.stream().mapToDouble(m -> m.value)
                            .average().orElse(0.0);
                    return new Model(list.get(0).key, avg); // [3]
                }))
        .subscribe(result -> { //[4]
            // do something
        });
```

1. Group based on key
2. Apply `buffer` to the grouped observable
3. Calculate average
4. The result is in form of `Model(group, average)`